# Where do I make the pause in this sentence

Tags: punctuation, pronunciation

I am a Catholic monk, in our breviaries, in the English edition, we have a response for the night prayer which goes: "Into your hands, Lord, I commend my spirit." How do I use this?

Is it

1. Into your hands, / Lord, I commend my spirit. Or,
2. Into your hands, Lord, / I commend my spirit.

You may find this question stupid, but, I am not a native speaker of English. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The commas represent pauses -- that's their purpose.  Where one pauses further when chanting is determined by the meter of the chant.

Comment: Not what you asked, but you should have a period or at least a semicolon after Catholic monk.  I suggest a pause after hands, and a longer pause after Lord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing "Lord" so normally you would pause AFTER the word.  You can see in [this YouTube example](http://youtu.be/DeRNA9c1hDI) that some versions of this particular exhortation use "Oh, Lord" which makes the break even more natural AFTER the word "Lord."

Comment: Yes. *Your* and *Lord* should fall in the same breath.